# Evaluating indefinite integral as a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration

Evaluate the following indefinite integral as a power series:

$$\int\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt$$

Help appreciated!

Comment: Where are you running into problems?  Is it in the conversion to power series, or is it in the integration of the series? (That changes the question entirely)

Comment: integrating it as a power series

Comment: This integral is called [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log{(1-t)} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n}$$

$$\int dt \frac{\log{(1-t)}}{t} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n^2}$$